# How I can define a QMap with struct as key

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I try to define a QMap which it's key is a C++ structure.

```
struct ProcInfo_S
{
    quint8 tech = 0;
    quint8 direction = 0;
    quint8 category = 0;
};

QMap<ProcInfo_S, uint64_t> G;
G[{2,3,4}] = 2;
```

But when I compile this code, I get the following compile error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::ProcInfo_S’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the elements in the map is determined by calling `operator<` of the keys. From [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html):

> [...] The key type of a QMap must provide operator<() specifying a total order. Since Qt 5.8.1 it is also safe to use a pointer type as key, even if the underlying operator<() does not provide a total order.

One way to implement it is for example:

```
struct ProcInfo_S
{
    quint8 tech = 0;
    quint8 direction = 0;
    quint8 category = 0;
    bool operator<( const ProcInfo_S& other) const {
         return std::tie(tech,direction,category) < std::tie(other.tech,other.direction,other.category);
    }
};
```